# InfoPath 2010: View signatures in different View(s)?

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I am creating an InfoPath Form with about 5 different views. 4 views need to be signed by the user after filling it out, and the last 1 is what I am having issues with.

I would like this last view to reflect all the signatures signed so far (ex. Person A signs View 1, signature from View 1 can be seen from View 5).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered here:
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/26599/92439.aspx#92439

Thanks anyway!